# Include same header file for different libs

Tags: c++, cmake, libs

I have a C++ project with the following structure:

```
CMakeLists.txt
code/
  libClient/
     CMakeLists.txt
     include/
        LibClient/
          lib_client.h
     src/
        lib_client.cpp
  libServer/
     CMakeLists.txt
     include/
        LibServer/
          lib_server.h
     src/
        lib_server.cpp
  libSDK/
     include/
       CMakeLists.txt
       LibSDK/
         lib.h
```

My root CMakeLists.txt has the following content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(libExample)


set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

add_subdirectory(code/libClient)
add_subdirectory(code/libServer)
add_subdirectory(code/libSDK)
```

Now, I would like to build the libs for the server and for the client as `.a` files. The `lib_client.cpp` includes the header files with

`#include <LibClient/lib_client.h>`

Up to here, it is all clear for me, but the header file `lib_client.h` includes the `lib.h` which is located at `/code/libSDK/include/LibSDK/lib.h` with

```
#ifndef LIBCLIENT_H
#define LIBCLIENT_H

#include <string>
#include <LibSDK/lib.h>
```

To make this work, I wrote the following content in the CMakelists.txt for the ClientLib:

```
project(LIBCLIENT)

add_library(
    Client_lib STATIC
    src/lib_client.cpp
        include/LibClient/lib_client.h
    )

target_include_directories(egoClient_lib PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
target_include_directories(egoClient_lib PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libSDK/include")   ###this line I think should be different.
```

My question is now, is it possible to avoid this line with the hard coded path? This `lib.h` is also used (included) in other header files in this project.

The CMakelists.txt for this lib.h has up to now only the content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(LIBSDK)
```

I thought about using the CMake `find_package()` method and write a `Find<package>.cmake` file, but I do not see any advantages of this because inside this file I also have to write the paths?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If Client_lib uses SDK_lib, you'll want to use the following in Client_lib's `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_link_libraries(Client_lib SDK_lib)
```

This will tell CMake that Client_lib uses SDK_lib. It will also automatically make the `PUBLIC` or `INTERFACE` include paths configured on SDK_lib (with `target_include_directories` in SDK_lib's `CMakeLists.txt`) available for Client_lib.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the fast reply. 
It is working now, after adding the lines 

target_include_directories(Client_lib PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
target_include_directories(Server_lib PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")

into the CMakeLists.txt of lib.h

But I would like to understand what the suggested line target_link_libraries(Client_lib SDK_lib)
would do, because the lib.h should not be compiled to a lib, only the server and the client.

Greetings.

Comment: So `lib.h` *is* part of a library, called `SDK_lib`. This is a so-called [INTERFACE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries) library since it does not have any source files to compile into a `.a` file. But any `PUBLIC` (or `INTERFACE`) include paths set on such a target (or certain other properties) do propagate via `target_link_libraries`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if your `libClient` and `libServer` depend on `libSDK`, you should rearrange your top-level CMake to look like the below. Also, based on your example project structure, your `add_subdirectory()` for the SDK should be `code/libSDK/include`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(libExample)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

add_subdirectory(code/libSDK/include)
add_subdirectory(code/libClient)
add_subdirectory(code/libServer)
```

You want to be sure to gather information about you SDK first, **before** traversing to the client and server directories.

---

Secondly, if you do not intend to build `libSDK` into a library, but simply use its headers, you can just define a new variable in your `libSDK` CMake file to specify the location of the headers:

```
project(LIBSDK)

set(SDK_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} CACHE INTERNAL "My SDK headers directory.")
```

Now, with a cached variable from the `libSDK` directory, we can use it in the other CMake files:

```
project(LIBCLIENT)

add_library(Client_lib STATIC
    src/lib_client.cpp
)

target_include_directories(Client_lib PUBLIC 
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
    "${SDK_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY}"
)
```

---

**EDIT**: As commented, to avoid the use of cache variables, you can also set the include directories variable with [`PARENT_SCOPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-normal-variable) to make the variable accessible from your client and server CMake files:

```
project(LIBSDK)

set(SDK_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PARENT_SCOPE)
```

Comment: Using cached variables to achieve this is generallly discouraged in modern CMake. It's better to define an [INTERFACE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries) library for `SDK_Lib` and set the include path on that target (see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58471946/cmake-include-same-header-file-for-different-libs/58472100#comment103295188_58472100) above).

Comment: @Mike.nl Added an alternative to using the cached variable. Agreed that it is better practice to define an interface library for this SDK, but the OP described that `lib.h` should *not* be pulled in as part of a library. Without a full understanding of the OP's use of the SDK, I tried to keep my explanation as simple as possible.